# how to prevent absolutely positioned element moving up with the keyboard in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a container which contains a code editor and a collapsed live preview like this

```
     <View style={style.editorWithLivePreview}>
        {
          questionObject
          && <CodeEditorsTab.Navigator>
            {
              Object.keys(questionObject.questionSetup.files)
                .map((filePath, idx) => {
                  const { files } = memorizedWebkataQuestionState.questionObject.questionSetup;
                  const { name } = files[filePath];
                  return <CodeEditorsTab.Screen name={`${name}Tab`} key={idx} options={{ tabBarLabel: name }}>
                    {(props) => <CodeEditor {...props}
                      codeEditorWebViewRef={(el) => {
                        codeEditorsRefs.current[name] = el;
                      }}
                      style={style}
                      onload={onCodeEditorLoad}
                      styleStringForDocumentInsideWebView={styleStringForDocumentInsideWebView}
                      onCodeEditorChanged={(code) => onCodeEditorChange(name, code)}
                    />}
                  </CodeEditorsTab.Screen>;
                })
            }
          </CodeEditorsTab.Navigator>
        }
        <View style={[style.containerWithRevealerBtn, {
          height: orientation === 'PORTRAIT' ? Dimensions.get('window').height - 130 : Dimensions.get('window').height - 105,
          transform:
            [{ translateX: livePreviewOpen ? 0 : Dimensions.get('window').width - 50 }],
          zIndex: livePreviewOpen ? 1 : undefined,
        }]}>
          <RevealerButton
            style={style}
            revealed={livePreviewOpen}
            toggleReveal={() => {
              setLocalState((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                livePreviewOpen: !prev.livePreviewOpen,
              }));
            }}
          />
          <View style={style.container}>
            <SecondaryTabBar
              style={style}
              activeTab={secondaryActiveTab}
              changeTab={(tabToSet) => {
                setSecondaryActiveTab(tabToSet);
              }}
            />
            {
              secondaryActiveTab === 'livePreview'
              && <LivePreview
                style={style}
                livePreviewWebViewRef={livePreviewWebViewRef}
                codeState={codeState}
                onMessageFromLivePreviewWebView={onMessageFromLivePreviewWebView}
              />
            }
            {
              secondaryActiveTab === 'validatedResult'
              && <ValidatedResult
                style={style}
                evaluationDetails={evaluationDetails}
              />
            }
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

The code is a bit too much due to the implementation details but this is how the app looks
[image]

marked in **red** is the container with the `style.editorWithLivePreview`.

[image]

marked in **blue** is the container with the `style.containerWithRevealerBtn` (the container which holds the revealer button and the **live preview**).

here are the styles

```
const style = {
  editorWithLivePreview: {
    flex:1,
    position:'relative',
  },
containerWithRevealerBtn: {
 flex: 1,
 position: 'absolute',
 width: '100%',
 bottom: 0,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 },
}
```

the live preview container is absolutely positioned relative to editorWithLivePreview.

[image]

When the keyboard opens the live preview container is also pushed up with the keyboard.
How to prevent this

Comment: any solution to the problem?

Comment: Any solution found yet?